# How to convert a PCollection<Long> having a single element to a java in-memory collection?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

So what I was trying to do is that I have the output of `Count` transform stored in a `PCollection<Long>` which now has only one element. It'd be really convenient if there was any method to convert this to Java in-memory collection. Essentially what I'm looking for is negation of `Create.of()` transform. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Beam, there is no provided way to do this. That said, whatever followup computation you would like to do could consume the single element as a side input to a `ParDo`. I would recommend converting directly to a `PCollectionView` when you do the `Count`; it is a good practice for combiners that have identity elements.

```java
PCollectionView<Long> count =
    input.apply(Combine.globally(Count.combineFn()).asSingletonView())

dummyCollection.apply(ParDo.of(new DoFnConsumingTheCount(count)).withSideInputs(count));
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at materialize in [Scio](https://github.com/spotify/scio/blob/a918b8108b6733e250318d0631bd7e36e36367ab/scio-core/src/main/scala/com/spotify/scio/values/SCollection.scala#L996-L1027).